# How do I manually enter in a Matrix of data?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, g++

I just want to hard code in a matrix using C++ (g++ 4.1.2), by default I went with a std::vector of std::vectors.

My guess is this can be done in one line I just don't know the correct syntax.

For example:

(1,2,5)

(9,3,6)

(7,8,4)

I thought it might be something like this -

```
  vector<int> v1(1,2,3);
  vector<int> v2(4,5,6);
  vector<int> v3(7,8,9);
  vector<vector<int>> vA(v1,v2,v3);
```

Normally, I wold read this info out of a text file, but I need to manually put in the numbers by hand and I have to use g++ 4.1.2

Comment: This lack all sorts of required detail. Are these std:vector vectors, or some other sort of vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not going to change the size or shape of this matrix and since you're hard-coding the values anyway, you may be better with a plain old array:

```
int matrix[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Otherwise, [Fred Nurk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079044/how-do-i-manually-enter-in-a-vector-of-vectors/6079086#6079086) is what you are looking for.

Comment: But if you want to resize, you'll need to copy into a vector.  At that point, it's simpler and easier to just use a couple for loops to initialize the vector.  I presumed resizing or something else from vector's interface was desired, but if not, I'd just go with an array too.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is the easiest (without C++0x):

```
vector<vector<int> > v (3);
for (int a = 0; a != 3; ++a) {
  v[a].resize(3);
  for (int b = 0; b != 3; ++b) {
    v[a][b] = a * 3 + b + 1;
  }
}
```

With 0x initializers, which I doubt that version of gcc supports:

```
vector<vector<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Comment: Your version of gcc doesn't support 0x initializers, that's why I said "With 0x initializers, which I doubt that version of gcc supports".